# Excel VBA to move data from table to table based on column name

Tags: vba, excel

I created a procedure that loops in all header columns of table 1 and search for the same header column in table 2 to update relveant cells based on matched column name.

This is the code for this procedure:

```
Do While i <= SourceTableColumnCount
ColumnName = sourceTable.HeaderRowRange(i).Value
                    On Error Resume Next
                    DestColumnIndex = destTable.Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:= True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Count
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            'In case column name in source table is not found in destination table
                        Else
                            destTable.DataBodyRange(DestRowIndex + 1, DestColumnIndex).Value =  sourceTable.DataBodyRange(r + 1, i).Value
                        End If
                    i = i + 1
Loop
```

The problem is DestColumnIndex is always 1. Although column name in destination table is matching column name in source table. It should work like this:

1- Go to first column in table 1 and get it's value
2- Go to table 2 and search for value from step 1
3- For the found result, get the range.column (Index of this column)
4- Set the cell value where range (Row, DestColumnIndex)

my problem is in step 3 where range.column is always 1 so the output of step 4 is always updating cell where column index is 1.

I hope the problem is clear.

Comment: I believe it runs into an error (Runtime 1004) when *i* is empty/zero and doesn't recover.

Comment: @user3819867: Actually it is working fine as the matching column is found. The problem that it is not getting the correct position of the found column, it is always set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do While i <= SourceTableColumnCount
ColumnName = sourceTable.HeaderRowRange(i).Value
                    On Error Resume Next
                    DestColumnIndex = destTable.Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column - destTable.Range.Column + 1 'why would you use .Count?, it is a single cell, its count will always be 1
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            'In case column name in source table is not found in destination table
                        Else
                            destTable.DataBodyRange(DestRowIndex + 1, DestColumnIndex).Value = sourceTable.DataBodyRange(r + 1, i).Value
                        End If
                    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Yea you are right, I did it by mistake and didn't notice until you said.